# Rails - redirect_to POST alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, post, redirect

NOTE : Question reformulated to be more clear

I would like to simulate the sending of a form to an external domain in a controller action (like a redirect_to an external domain in POST with POST params). IE : Send the POST request with the params, and render the HTML results in the browser.

What is the best way to do it in Rails 3?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want to do? Are you wanting to have a use click a link which eventually calls some POST action?

Comment: The question has been reformulated. Basically ; I want to send a form to an external domain ; but doing it at the view level will result in some ugly code + JS. I was wondering if there is a clean way to do it at the controller level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can just execute the POST on the server side, collect the response and then do whatever you like with it.  It's not unlike making a server side call to your favourite REST API and then rendering the response to the client.

You probably want to start with a library that provides a nice interface for server side POST.  I'd suggest looking at https://github.com/nahi/httpclient